# How to throw an exception, if an object structure is not matching/fitting another one

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I will read user input objects which should be in well-formed.

That is, the input objects could now have any key or sub-structure that is not defined in the interface.

How could I throw an exception, if a user gives an invalid object?

## Pre-defined interface

```
  export interface InputStructureInterface {
      "tableName": string,
      "viewType": string,
      "structureName": string,
      "sections": Array<Section>,
  }

  interface Section{
      "name": string,
      "fields": Array<Field>
  }

  interface Field{
      "fieldName": string,
      "relationType": string,
      "relationName": null,
      "fieldUi": FieldUi
  }

  interface FieldUi {
      "fieldType": string,
      "label": strin
  }
```

## Valid input structure

This structure is a subset under the defined `InputStructureInterface`

```
  {
    "tableName": "User",
    "viewType": "List View",
    "structureName": "personal_data_settings_list_view",
    "sections": [
      {
        "name": null,
        "fields": [
          {
            "fieldName": "Name",
            "relationType": null,
            "relationName": null,
            "fieldUi": {
              "fieldType": "string",
              "label": "Name"
            },
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

## Invalid input structure

Because `viewTypeTHIS_IS_A_TYPO`, `nameTHIS_IS_A_TYPO` are not present on the interface

```
{
  "tableName": "User",
  "viewTypeTHIS_IS_A_TYPO": "List View",
  "structureName": "personal_data_settings_list_view",
  "sections": [
    {
      "nameTHIS_IS_A_TYPO": null,
      "fields": [
        {
          "fieldNameTHIS_IS_A_TYPO": "Name"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The TypeScript will just enforce the types in compile time. If you want to make this kind of validations you need to use some kind of json-schema validation library. Like this one for example: https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv

**UPDATE**

For example, using this library (https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv) you can do something like this:

```
import * as Ajv from 'ajv';
const ajv = new Ajv();

const schema = {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "tableName": { "type": "string" },
        "viewType": { "type": "string" },
        "structureName": { "type": "string" },
        "sections": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": [
                {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "name": { "type": ["string", "null"] },
                        "fields": {
                            "type": "array",
                            "items": [
                                {
                                    "type": "object",
                                    "properties": {
                                        "fieldName": { "type": "string" },
                                        "relationType": { "type": ["string", "null"] },
                                        "relationName": { "type": ["string", "null"] },
                                        "fieldUi": {
                                            "fieldType": { "type": "string" },
                                            "label": { "type": "string" }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "required": ["fieldName", "relationType", "relationName"],
                                    "additionalProperties": false
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "required": ["name", "fields"],
                    "additionalProperties": false
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "required": ["tableName", "viewType", "structureName"],
    "additionalProperties": false
};

const validate = ajv.compile(schema);
let valid = validate(data); // <-- pass your json object here

if (!valid) {
    console.log(validate.errors);
}
```

To install the library: `npm install ajv`

Comment: Take a look, I updated the answer and I think this code will work to you. You just need to make your desired changes to put it on your code.